me da error al instalar kivy en Mac
Me muestra siempre el mismo error al instalar kivy en Mac, he intentado muchas soluciones y nada. Me he fijado en la pagina de kivy que esta compatible con python3 version de 3.7 a 3.12 y la ultima version es python3 version 3.13.0. he instalado la 3.12 y tampoco.
El error es este:

6 warnings and 8 errors generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy
Failed to build kivy
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (kivy)```


Hola, asegúrate de ejecutar pip usando Python 3.12 o de crear y activar un entorno virtual con esta versión del interprete y no con Python 3.13. Kivy aún no es compatible con Python 3.13. Se podría instalar desde el repo de GIt pero sería una versión no estable, se necesitan instalar las dependencias y compilar el paquete y desconozco los problemas que tiene abiertos actualmente.

El error en si es un problema de compilación por clang de las partes nativas escritas en C o de algunas de las dependencias del paquete, puede ser un error de enlazado, falta de dependencias, compilador desactualizado, etc Pero dado que se proporcionan binarios precompilados, esto no debería pasar, lo más probable es que sigas intentando instalarlo en Python 3.13 aunque tengas  Python 3.12 instalado. La traza completa del error sería de ayuda.
